# Mock a class instance common in many classes in spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am new to spring concepts. I am trying to write a Junit for one of the class's method. I want to mock spring framework `JdbcTemplate` class that is being used as `@Autowired` from multiple location. But I don't want to use `@Mock` in each class. Is there any way I can mock this class and that can be used from multiple location by using `@Autowired`.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a non-answer, but I would not recommend using `Spring` to `inject dependencies` when unit testing.  If you are using `constructor injection`, then you can simply call the constructor from the unit test and pass in your mock or test double manually.  This makes it very clear and explicit from the unit test what the supplied dependency is for the purposes of the test.  If you are using setter injection, you can do the same.  Don't materialize the class under test via `Spring`, just construct the class under test from your `junit` test class, and supply the dependencies you want on that class imperatively.

Comment: Hey Jim thanks for the response!!!! The class which contains the method has multiple Autowired beans out which I want to mock only JdbcTemplate bean. But when I am using @Mock jdbcTemplte in my test class then while creating the bean for original class I am getting error nosucbeanfound error for the jdbcTemplate. Could you please help?

Comment: How are you obtaining the class under test from Spring?  It sounds like your autowired annotations are not finding the class to be injected on the classpath.  I would need to see a bit more code.  @Mock is a mockito annotation, so it sounds like you are trying to use that framework to create your mock.

Comment: Here is my test class.public class test{ @@Mock JdbcTemplate a; @@Autowired ABC abc;@Before public void init(){MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);} @@Test public void test(){abc.somemethod()}}

Comment: Here is the original class for which I am wrting the test. public class ABC{@Autowires JdbcTemplate a; public void somemethod(){//some implementation}}

Comment: Now in the test class original class autowiring is not happening. I am getting exceptions like NoSuchBeanExists for jdbcTemplate>

Comment: You should be using `@InjectMocks ABC abc;` instead of `@Autowired ABC abc;` in your test class.

Answer (score 0):

Define a spring profile specific for your tests (as example "test"), in that profile create the `JdbcTemplate` bean with a mock library and with the annotation `@Profile("test")`. In that way this mock will be created only when the "test" profile is active.

Add the annotation `@Profile("!test")` to the real `JdbcTemplate` bean so it will not be created in the test profile.

Then add the `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation on top of you test class.